# How to make local keyboard input move only the local player, not everyone in networked multiplayer?

Tags: unity, unity-networking

I am working on Unity Networking and following this Tanks Networking tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V6wEvT6G92M

Problem is that the keyboard inputs move all the tanks in the scene. It is not detecting the local tank. And when I run the game all tanks shows the same movement but it is not giving any error. I have followed all steps in the tutorial and searched all solutions on the google. This step in Tutorial is at 11:48.

Implemented Code is:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput;
using UnityEngine.Networking;


public class TankController : NetworkBehaviour {

// Use this for initialization

[Header("Movement Variables")]
[SerializeField] float movementSpeed = 5.0f;
[SerializeField] float turnSpeed = 45.0f;

[Header("Camera Position Variables")]
[SerializeField] float cameraDistance = 16f;
[SerializeField] float cameraHeight = 16f;

Rigidbody localRigidBody;
Transform mainCamera;
Vector3 cameraOffset;


void Start () {
    if (!isLocalPlayer)
    {
        Destroy(this);
        return;
    }
        localRigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        cameraOffset = new Vector3(0f, cameraHeight, -cameraDistance);
        mainCamera = Camera.main.transform;
        MoveCamera();


}

// Update is called once per frame
void FixedUpdate () {


        float turnAmount = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("HorizontalUI");
        float moveAmount = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("VerticalUI");

        Vector3 deltaTranslation = transform.position + transform.forward * movementSpeed * moveAmount * Time.deltaTime;
        localRigidBody.MovePosition(deltaTranslation);

        Quaternion deltaRotation = Quaternion.Euler(turnSpeed * new Vector3(0, turnAmount, 0) * Time.deltaTime);
        localRigidBody.MoveRotation(localRigidBody.rotation * deltaRotation);

        MoveCamera();

}

void MoveCamera() {
        mainCamera.position = transform.position;
        mainCamera.rotation = transform.rotation;
        mainCamera.Translate(cameraOffset);
        mainCamera.LookAt(transform);

}
}
```

I have also checked the auto create player in the spawn info as suggested in some solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [isLocalPlayer](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.NetworkBehaviour-isLocalPlayer.html) property, as you did in `Start()`. Use it wherever you want to keep things 'local':

```
void FixedUpdate () {

    if(this.isLocalPlayer)

        float turnAmount = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("HorizontalUI");
        float moveAmount = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("VerticalUI");

        Vector3 deltaTranslation = transform.position + transform.forward * movementSpeed * moveAmount * Time.deltaTime;
        localRigidBody.MovePosition(deltaTranslation);

        Quaternion deltaRotation = Quaternion.Euler(turnSpeed * new Vector3(0, turnAmount, 0) * Time.deltaTime);
        localRigidBody.MoveRotation(localRigidBody.rotation * deltaRotation);

        MoveCamera();

    }
}
```

Comment: Did not worked.